# Download and install button in greyed out in Eclipse for Apache Tomcat v8.0

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I want Eclipse to download and install Apache Tomcat server environment but that option is greyed out for me

[image]

Any idea what might be missing?

```
Eclipse details :
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars.2 Release(4.5.2)
Java 8
```

Comment: Problem persists in Eclipse Neon.

Comment: This might not be an option for everyone, but one thing you can try is using a different version of tomcat. Going to an older one worked for me.

Comment: This question is also asked (and not answered) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567560/eclipse-tomcat-server-download-and-install-button-not-clickable)

Answer (score 3):

It appears that this is caused by the lack of installable runtimes being defined for a given version of Tomcat in eclipse's `org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core` plugin.

In my case, I had eclipse "Photon" installed on my Windows box. In this version, the `Download and Install` button is active for Tomcat 8.0, but it is not for 8.5:

[image]

To enable it, I had to add two entries to the `plugin.xml` in the `org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core` jar, located in the plugins dir:

[image]

The entries are as follows, under the `org.eclipse.wst.server.core.installableRuntimes` extension node:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.wst.server.core.installableRuntimes">
    ...
    <runtime
        id="org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtime.85"
        licenseUrl="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt"
        archiveUrl="http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.38/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.38-windows-x86.zip"
        archivePath="apache-tomcat-8.5.38"
        archiveSize="11402963"
        fileCount="645"
        os="win32"/>
    <runtime
        id="org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtime.85"
        licenseUrl="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt"
        archiveUrl="http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.38/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.38.tar.gz"
        archivePath="apache-tomcat-8.5.38"
        archiveSize="9672042"
        fileCount="641"
        os="linux"/>
</extension>
```

I just chose the latest 8.5 binaries available from `archive.apache.org` and obtained the `archiveSize` and `fileCount` values with `ls` and `find | wc`:

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 cody group  9672042 Feb  5 07:21 apache-tomcat-8.5.38.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 cody group 11402963 Feb  5 07:21 apache-tomcat-8.5.38-windows-x86.zip

$ find apache-tomcat-8.5.38 -type f | wc -l
641
```

After updating the plugin jar, I modified `eclipse.ini` to add the `-clean` flag such that all plugin cache is purged. Remember to remove this after re-launching, as it will obviously cause eclipse to start up much more slowly:

```
-clean
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar
--launcher.library
...
```

Once eclipse is up, the button is now enabled for 8.5 and functions as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can download tomcat separatly, than you can specify particulare installation path

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be a fixed bug ([here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472933)) . But as a java developer I personally prefer to configure my development environment by myself, it's a very good source to learn more about common issues in development and deployment.

Comment: Clearly there are other causes of this problem, because it still occurs.