# eclipse tomcat server "download and install" button not clickable

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm trying to install tomcat server in eclipse, but in step when "download and install" button should be pressed (like in the pic) it's not clickable. Button is grey and cannot be pressed.

[dowload and install pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNf40.jpg)

Comment: One thing you can try is selecting different versions of tomcat, going to an older one worked for me.

Comment: This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533711/download-and-install-button-in-greyed-out-in-eclipse-for-apache-tomcat-v8-0/54912098#54912098).